# How to implement contact-tracing in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, contact-tracing-api

I want to implement contact-tracing functionality in my react-native app but the libraries that I have found are not yet ready to be used in production. How can I implement it in my app?

Comment: Please mention which libraries you have tried so far.

Comment: https://github.com/wix-incubator/rn-contact-tracing